# Splitting JSON topics into sections in tableview

Tags: ios, json

I am reading articles from a webserver, which come in JSON format, and displaying them in tableview.  I want to implement section headers, with each section being a topic.  So far there are only 3 topics and the code in 'numberOfSectionsInTableView' below correctly determines that there are 3 sections.

My trouble is with the next function, 'numberOfRowsInSection'.  I cannot figure out how to determine the number of rows in each section.  I have looked at other answers on stack overflow and the reason none have helped me is that I have a variable number of sections and rows, whereas most other questioners have a fixed number of sections.

Any ideas?

FYI 'news' is the array of articles in JSON format.  I follow this great tutorial: [JSON](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJZcD3hfs3k)

My header file looks like this:

```
NSDictionary *newsArticle;
NSArray *news;
NSMutableData *data;
NSString *tempTopic;
NSString *lastTempTopic;
NSMutableArray *topicList;
```

and my implementation file looks like this:

```
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
lastTempTopic = @"";
int numTopics = 0;
topicList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<news.count; i++) {
    newsArticle = [news objectAtIndex:i];
    tempTopic = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"topic"];
    if ([tempTopic isEqualToString:lastTempTopic])
    {
    }
    else
        numTopics++;
    lastTempTopic = tempTopic;
}
return numTopics;
}


- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [news count];
}
```

Here is a generic bit of the JSON code I am parsing.  I want topics 1,2,3 to become the respective sections with appropriate number of rows.

[{"title":"title1","original_url":"http://originalurl1.html","topic":"Topic 1","display_url":"display.url1","author":"Author1","published_on":"date1","text_blocks":[{"TextBlock":"article content 1"}]},{"title":"title2","original_url":"http://originalurl2.html","topic":"Topic 1","display_url":"display.url2","author":"Author2","published_on":"date2","text_blocks":[{"TextBlock":"article content 2"}]},{"title":"title3","original_url":"http://originalurl3.html","topic":"Topic 1","display_url":"display.url3","author":"Author3","published_on":"date3","text_blocks":[{"TextBlock":"article content 3"}]},{"title":"title4","original_url":"http://originalurl4.html","topic":"Topic 2","display_url":"display.url4","author":"Author4","published_on":"date4","text_blocks":[{"TextBlock":"article content 4"}]},
{"title":"title5","original_url":"http://originalurl5.html","topic":"Topic 2","display_url":"display.url5","author":"Author5","published_on":"date5","text_blocks":[{"TextBlock":"article content 5"}]}
{"title":"title6","original_url":"http://originalurl6.html","topic":"Topic 2","display_url":"display.url6","author":"Author6","published_on":"date6","text_blocks":[{"TextBlock":"article content 6"}]}
{"title":"title7","original_url":"http://originalurl7.html","topic":"Topic 3","display_url":"display.url7","author":"Author7","published_on":"date7","text_blocks":[{"TextBlock":"article content 7"}]}]

Comment: For that you have to create an array including array of news..

Comment: 1:count your dic , that would be numberOfRowsInSection return value;
2:you can get cell value by key on you dic ex([dic objectforkey@"key"]);
3:you can count you new dic again , that you can get the numberOfRowsInSection value and get all value .

hope can help you .

Comment: Can you post your JSON? It's difficult to understand the problem with the data if we can't see any data.

Comment: MishieMoo, please see the code that I added.